# Why don't lambda expressions require <functional>, but function<void()> does?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have some code use lambda expression like it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main(){
    std::vector<int> vi={3,1};
    std::sort(vi.begin(),vi.end(),[](int x,int y){
        return x<y;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Which doesn't require  `#include< functional>` to compile, but if I use a variable to store the lambda function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
int main(){
    std::vector<int> vi={3,1};
    std::function<void()> compf=[](int x,int y){
        return x<y;
    };
    std::sort(vi.begin(),vi.end(),compf);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I need to include `<functional>` to compile, why? And why `sort()` doesn't also include `<functional>` already?

Comment: Are you under the impression that a lambda is a std::function? It's not; there's a conversion involved when you store it to `compf`.

Comment: Because lambda expressions are part of the language. `std::function` is part of the standard library and so requires a header include.

Comment: @PaulRooney, To be fair, `for (int i : {1, 2, 3})` also requires a header include despite no explicit standard library usage.

Comment: @chris true. I always found that a bit weird.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Because a lambda expression is a core language feature, provided by the compiler. `std::function` is a library feature, implemented in code. Note that you don't need to include anything to store the lambda in a variable.

```
auto f = [](int x, int y){ return x < y; };
```

You only need to include `<functional>` if you plan to store it in a `std::function` (because that's where it's implemented).

You seem to be under the impression that the type of a lambda is a `std::function`. It is not. Every lambda expression has its own unique, unnameable type. I captured that type above, with `auto`. `std::function` is a more general type that can store *any* function-like object with the appropriate signature. For example, I can create a `std::function<int(int,int)>` object, and assign to it a normal function, a function object, and a lambda.

```
#include <functional>
int minus_func(int a, int b) { return a - b; }

struct plus_t {
    int operator()(int a, int b) const { return a + b; }
};

int main() {
    auto mult_lambda = [](int a, int b) { return a * b; };

    std::function<int(int,int)> func;
    func = minus_func;
    func = plus_t{};
    func = mult_lambda;
}
```

There's also a cost to that generality, in the form of dynamic allocation, and indirection. Whereas using a lambda through a variable of its actual type is very often inlined.

Comment: `std::function<>` implementations may have static storage as to avoid dynamic allocation for callables below a certain size. This is similar to the small string optimization.

Comment: How is the line _"func=plus_t{}"_ supposed to work? Does it create an anonymous object of type _"plus_t"_?

Comment: Don't you mean "and assign to it" rather than "and assign it to"?

Comment: @blackpen: Yes, that's what it does. It uses uniform initialization syntax. I could have also used the more traditional `func = plus_t();`.

Comment: @user2296177 "Must" have for certain objects (function pointers and a few others), "may"  have for objects (typically under a certain size), but there is no mandate that small lambdas must ever be stored with SOO in a std::function (this is a quality of library implementation issue, however).  One popular std library (MSVC's) will SOO any callable no bigger than two `std::string`s (which themselves have SOO for short strings) if I remember rightly.

Answer (score 6):

lambda functions are part of the language -- independent of any libraries.

`std::function`, on the other hand, is part of the standard library and is defined in the standard library header file `functional`.

Hence, use of

```
std::sort(vi.begin(),vi.end(),[](int x,int y){
    return x<y;
});
```

does not require `functional` to be `#include`d while use of

```
std::function<void()> compf=[](int x,int y){
    return x<y;
};
std::sort(vi.begin(),vi.end(),compf);
```

requires `functional` to be `#include`d.